# how to add two IDs in where condition in joomla query?

Tags: joomla

I want to add two IDs in where condition in joomla.

This is the my query.

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT content_item_id FROM #_contentitem_tag_map **WHERE tag_id = id1 and id2**");
```

How can i filter this two ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$id_1 = XXX;
$id_2 = XXX; 

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('content_item_id')))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__contentitem_tag_map'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('tag_id') . ' = ' . (int)$id_1, 'AND')
      ->where($db->quoteName('tag_id') . ' = ' . (int)$id_2 );
$db->setQuery($query);
```

You will notice here that I've used proper Joomla coding standard for your database query which should be used at **all** times. Using native mysql is not the way forward.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT content_item_id FROM #_contentitem_tag_map WHERE tag_id IN (id1,id2);
```

USE mysql IN

> id IN (2,3,...)